# Expandable TextView for RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I want to create `TextView` for `RecyclerView` which will shows only 4 lines and one button, which will expands `TextView`. I have been looking for solution in Google for week, but found nothing for `RecyclerView`. Please, give me an advise or code example.

I want to create something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In RecyclerView Item Layout, use `android:maxLines="4"` attribute for the 1st textview for setting it to 4 lines.
Then set onClickListener for the second textview(showing expand) and set 1st textviews maxlines to 100 or so. Like

```
holder.expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            holder.title.setMaxLines(100);
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's so simple and it works. Thank you very much!

Comment: Check out [this project](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView).